# How can change the height of the chart in stimulsoft report dynamicly?

Tags: charts, report, stimulsoft

I have a stimulsoft report that it's contain a chart.Now I want to change the size of my chart in my report dynamicly?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are Height and Width properties of the chart that you can change.